# Wildfly 21 standalone.xml is overwritten when a war file is deployed

Tags: wildfly

I just upgrade to Wildfly 21 from Wildfly 14 and stopping and starting the server works fine.  However, whenever  I deploy or re-deploy a war file, my modified standalone.xml is overwritten to the default version.  Stopping and restarting the server doesn't rewrite my standalone.xml file.  I can't find any mention of this via google.  Help!

Comment: Do you modify the `standalone.xml` while the server is running?

Comment: No I didn't.  I shutdown the server before modifying standalone.xml.  I figured out what the problem is:  Whenever I deploy a war file, standalone.xml is overwritten with the current values, including everything I have changed, but with all comments removed.  This doesn't happen when I shutdown and restart Wildfly.  I consider this a bug!

Comment: Ah I see. That is actually not a bug. You should be using the web console or CLI to configure the server. The `standalone.xml` just represents the storage of the management model which is how the server is actually configured.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I like to put comments at all the changes that I made.  I will find another way to do this.

Comment: One option is to use CLI scripts to configure your server. You can add comments to the CLI scripts.